# Why am I getting KeyError in Python3 in the following piece of code?

Tags: python-3.6

```
    d = { ' dog ' : ' has a tail and goes woof! ' ,' cat ' : ' says  meow ' ,' mouse':' chased by cats ' }

    word=input('Enter a word: ')
    print('The definition is:', d.get(word))


    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<pyshell#429>", line 1, in <module>
        print('The definition is: ', d[word])
    KeyError: 'dog'
```

I entered  dog as my key value expecting it to print out: ' has a tail and goes woof! ' but instead i got a KeyError. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are trailing and leading white spaces in the string, e.g. ' dog ', You will never find the key in that way. This code should work fine:

```
d = { 'dog' : 'has a tail and goes woof!' ,'cat': 'says  meow', ' mouse':'chased by cats' }

word=input('Enter a word: ')
print('The definition is:', d.get(word.strip()))
```

I've added `word.strip()` at the end to ignore trailing and leading white spaces in the input

Comment: I added word.strip() as you had advised and the code runs but instead it prints out:                                                                                                  'Enter a word: dog'
'The definition is: None' Why do i get this output instead of 'has a tail and goes woof!' @MazziottiRaffaele

Comment: Never mind I reviewed it and it prints out exactly what it should when I entered a key value. I had to take out the white spaces between the commas as well. I appreciate your input very much @Mazziotti Raffaele. Thanks a bunch.